# How to make this recursive function extract uppercase letters from a string?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, uppercase

So the function should return all the uppercase letters from the string but it returns only the first letter IF it's the capital letter. So I believe the `i + 1` isn't working. And also, I have to use recursion for this code. I'm not allowed to use `isupper()`, or any other "shortcuts". So does anyone see what's going wrong in the code?

```
string Return_Caps(const string& s, int pos = 0){
    string temp;
    string a;
    if(s[pos] < 'A' && s[pos] > 'Z'){ // if the position does not have any capital letters, return a
        return a;
    }
    else{
        if(s[pos] >= 'A' && s[pos] <= 'Z'){ 
            temp = temp + s[pos];
            Return_Caps(s, pos + 1);
        }
    }
    return temp; 
}
```

Comment: `Return_Caps(s, i + 1);` - where is `i` defined or given a value? Should probably be: `Return_Caps(s, pos + 1);`! Also - where do you give `a` a value?

Comment: you're right! I meant pos +1

Comment: still gives the same errors thought... :(

Comment: See second part of my comment! What happens with `return a;` when `a` hasn't been assigned anything?

Comment: You should use your debugger and step through the call. It may reveal quite a bit.

Comment: There are multiple things that are wrong with the shown code. The correct solution is at most four or five lines of code in the recursive function. And there's no need to declare any variables in the recursive function. If whatever you come up with is more than that, there must be something wrong with it.

Comment: Alright, so I added pos as an int parameter, made the changes you guys suggested, and stepped through each call in the debugger. I had to run the debugger a couple of times to get to the error, and now it works! Thanks a million, everyone! I'll add the edits here as soon as I finish my homework :)